# Scraping website with many pages with R and rvest

Tags: r, function, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract some movies from IMDB with rvest in a data frame in R (called IMDB data). I tried debugging on my on but it doesn't work. If someone knows a better way or another way to add the number of the page to the URLs I would be thankful.

MY problem is when I tried to run the code for many pages define by the "**%d**", I get an error:

```
Error in data.frame(title = page %>% html_nodes("h3 a") %>% html_text(),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 103, 100, 93, 308, 110, 205, 201, 200, 87
```

My Code is the following:

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("xml2")
install.packages("purr")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


imdb <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&release_date=2017,2017&title_type=feature&page=%d&sort=moviemeter,asc&ref_=adv_nxt")

map_df(1:100, function(i){

  page <- read_html(sprintf(imdb,i))

  data.frame(title = page %>% html_nodes("h3 a")%>%html_text(),
             genre = page%>%html_nodes(".genre")%>%html_text(),
             PG = page%>%html_nodes(".certificate")%>%html_text(),
             rating = page%>%html_nodes(".ratings-imdb-rating")%>%html_text(),
             director = page%>%html_nodes(".lister-item-content a:nth-child(1)")%>%html_text(),
             Year = page%>%html_nodes(".text-muted.unbold")%>%html_text(),
             Actor1= page%>%html_nodes(".ghost+ a")%>%html_text(),
             Actor2= page%>%html_nodes("a:nth-child(4)")%>%html_text(),
             Actor3= page%>%html_nodes("a:nth-child(5)")%>%html_text(),
             Actor4= page%>%html_nodes("a:nth-child(6)")%>%html_text(),
             Gross = page%>%html_nodes(".sort-num_votes-visible span:nth-child(2)")%>%html_text(),
             Votes = page%>%html_nodes(".ghost~ .text-muted+ span")%>%html_text()

  )

}) -> imdb_data
```

Thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Is such a process allowed under their Terms of Use?

Comment: IMDB provide data for download - [see here](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces/). There are also tools to download and process the data - [see here](https://github.com/hadley/data-movies).